# Flutter GetX put internalition translations in different files for each language

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, translation, flutter-getx

Hi I want to translate my app and for that I tried using the GetX package. The basics are working fine, but I think it is not too clean to have all the different translations in one file like shown in the example:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class Messages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          'hello': 'Hello World',
        },
        'de_DE': {
          'hello': 'Hallo Welt',
        }
      };
}
```

Ideally I would like to have one file for each language. But GetX translations expects only one file:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: themeData,
      translations: AppTranslations(),
      locale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do here to make this cleaner? I couldnt find anything on this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have set up an OOP and test-supported structure for your problem. It should fix your problem

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GetMaterialApp(
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    theme: themeData,
    translations: Language(),
    locale: const Locale('en', 'EN'),
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('de', 'DE'),
    home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
  );
}
}


class Language extends Translations {
  final BaseLanguage frLanguage;
  final BaseLanguage enLanguage;

  Language({required this.frLanguage, required this.enLanguage});

  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    'fr_FR': frLanguage.language,
    'en_EN': enLanguage.language,
  };
}

abstract class BaseLanguage {
  Map<String, String> get language;
}

class EnLanguage implements BaseLanguage {
  @override
  Map<String, String> get language => {'test': 'English Language Translation'};
}

class FrLanguage implements BaseLanguage {
  @override
  Map<String, String> get language => {'test': 'French Language Translation'};
}
```

Comment: you need to pass the languages in the when you call Language() I think. But that might work. Ill give it a try

Comment: @Chris yes you should use it exactly as you think

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the translations class is a `Map` holding `Maps`.

Put each language-map in its own class.

```dart
return GetMaterialApp(
   locale: Get.deviceLocale,
   fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
   translations: AppTranslations(),
   //...
);


class AppTranslations extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys =>
      {'en_US': EnUSTranslations.map, 'de_DE': DeDETranslations.map};
}


class EnUSTranslations {
  static Map<String, String> get map => {'hello': 'Hello World'};
}


class DeDETranslations {
  static Map<String, String> get map => {'hello': 'Hallo Welt'};
}
```